# How to fetch data from database with json_encode of ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I use ajax to fetch data from DB. And I chose alert(valData) in success function to test the data, but unlucky nothing return from 
ajax. Then I tested

```
select contact from IDC WHERE id='5';
```

It works fine in mysql cmd line.

Here is my js code:

```
var stNum = 5;
$.ajax({
        dataType:'json',
        type:"POST",
        url:"get_ajax_csc.php",
        data:{stNum:stNum},
        success:function(data) 
        {
         var valData = data;
         alert(valData);
         $('#stContact').val(data.stCnt);
         $('#stPhone').val(data.stPho);
        }
      });
```

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="divFir">
    <label>Contact:</label><input type="text" id="stContact" ><br />
    <label>Phone:</label><input type="text" id="stPhone" ><br />
</div>
```

Here is get_ajax_csc.php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['stNum']))
{   
 include("DB.php"); 
 $q=$_POST["stNum"];
 $sql="select contact,phone from IDC WHERE id='".$q."';";
 $sel = $conn->query($sql); 

 $arr = $sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $tmpArr = array(
    'stCnt'=>$arr['contace'],
    'stPho'=>$arr['phone']
    );
 echo json_encode($tmpArr);
 }

 if(isset($_POST['htmlCnt']))
{   
include("DB.php");
$htcnt=stripslashes(".$_POST['htmlCnt'].");
........
}
 ?>
```

Here is DB.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$pwd=$_SESSION['password'];
$user=$_SESSION['user'];

try 
{
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=x.x.x.x;port=3306;dbname=hpc',$user,$pwd);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  echo "account or pwd wrong <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=index.html'>";
    exit;
}  
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, true);
?>
```

It seems nothing wrong in my code, but I cann't fetch data from database

I have found that stripslashes() made ajax return nothing. When I shielded this method (//stripslashes()), it worked fine. Why stripslashes can influence my ajax return data?

Comment: I have few questions from when the code stops working? Whether it works? and i can see the DB.php you are using session password and user for PDO connection. How it will work? You need fill the username and password that you used in creation of hpc database.

Comment: @AjmalPraveen,I have logged on, so  PDO connection is not a question. I clicked a button, and ajax of js will fetch data from DB. These data of contact and phone will show in the input.

Comment: use `header('Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8');` in get_ajax_csc.php so the file is sending json and not html code.

Comment: oh and your code is prone to sql injections

Comment: @JoshuaK, header('Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8'); in get_ajax_csc.php works fail again

Comment: Your database credentials should definitely **not** be in `$_SESSION`. Check your browser's *Network* console and see what the server is actually responding with

Comment: @Phil, oh my cod. I found stripslashes() made ajax return nothing. See my update

Comment: @JoshuaK,@cale_b, oh my cod. I found stripslashes() made ajax return nothing. See my update

Comment: @Snow and what do you think should your code do now? Now it's broken. nobody said you should work with stripslashes... stripslashes is never used in modern php programming. There is (normally) no need for this function! call the get_ajax_csc.php file in browser and take a look at the response. I think it's the wrong response type or there are characters in the response, they broke your json (empty lines or something like this). Use Ctrl+Shift+K to open the developer tools (FF) and take a look at the server responses and error messages in the console tab.

Answer (score 0):

I found that:

```
$htcnt=stripslashes(".$_POST['htmlCnt'].");
```

change to:

```
$htcnt=stripslashes($_POST['htmlCnt']);
```